# How to make rotation translated from analog stick input less "jumpy"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, rotation, controls

I'm making a game (in Unity) in which the character has a pointer rotating around it. The pointer defines the direction in which the character is going to move.

As it is, the way the pointer moves feels very "jumpy". I would like to make it more natural/smoother but I don't really have an idea on how to approach this problem.

Here's how I rotate the pointer around the player:

```
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),
            y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (x != 0 || y != 0) 
        {
            toRotate.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Atan2(y, x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg));
        }
```

I do this in the `Update()` function.

`toRotate` is a `Transform`

Comment: Try Quaternion.Lerp ... it functions the same as the other lerp/slerp functions for smooth movement.

Comment: Quaternion.Lerp works pretty well, thank you! Are there any other ways to achieve a smoother rotation though? Or is lerping the way to go?

Comment: Slerp is another option, just depends how you want it to look. Besides those two, nothing that i know of

Comment: I see, thank you very much for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sichi pointed out, the way to do this is to use `Quaternion.Lerp` or `Quaternion.Slerp` on the rotation.

This works fairly well.

```
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")
    float y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    float lerpAmount= 10;

    if (x != 0 || y != 0) 
    {
        toRotate.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(
            toRotate.rotation,
            Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Atan2(y, x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg),
            lerpAmount * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Quarternion.RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html).

```
float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")
float y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
float stepSize = 10 * Time.deltaTime;

if (x != 0 || y != 0) 
{
    var currentRotation = toRotate.rotation;
    var targetEuler = new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Atan2(y, x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
    var targetRotation = Quarternion.Euler(targetEuler);
    toRotate.rotation = Quarternion.RotateTowards(currentRotation, targetRotation, stepSize);
}
```